# How to access secure web services from a desktop application?

Tags: java, security, desktop-application

I'm writing a Java desktop application that will be available to the public. It will contact backend APIs via HTTPS using Jersey client.

I don't know anything about using certificates in desktop apps but from what I've found out so far I'll need to create an SSLContext that reads a public certificate from a KeyStore that is protected by a password.

I'm assuming I can distribute the contents of the KeyStore by packaging it in the Jar of my app. But I don't see how I can securely make the key store password available to the app. I don't want the users to have to enter it manually.

Comment: Just a bit of feedback, we can infer you are using Java, but its better to explicitly state the language you are using.

Comment: Good suggestion @GrandmasterB. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally read public keys without the password.  The default `cacerts` file comes with the password `changeit` but can be read without the password.

If you use a commercial certificate, Java may be able to connect without needing significant setup.